# Term/source for the "official" 2 line episode summary?

Tags: terminology, distribution

Across several different content providers and episode listings, often an identical summary of a tv episode is provided. That is to say, if you are browsing Netflix, or Hulu, or your cable box's channel guide, or the tv listings in the newspaper, or Google, and looking at a particular episode of a tv show, the exact same 2 line/sentence description/summary is provided for the episode. Is there a term for this particular description?

Answer (score 1):

This may simply be called a "blurb".

> blurb (n.):  a short description of a book, movie, or other product written for promotional purposes and appearing on the cover of a book or in an advertisement.

[source](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS756US756&ei=I5dBWqfYNcGZmQGG5bnAAw&q=define%20blurb&oq=define%20blurb&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l2j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l5.13432.14021.0.14282.5.5.0.0.0.0.138.376.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.3.375...0i20i263i264k1j0i20i264k1.0.sWC98_R8Vik)

Comment: I'm familiar with the term blurb, but I'm wondering if that encapsulates the "official" identical summary circulated across sources. The official blurb maybe?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. The definition I found _does_ say it's "written for promotional purposes".